# Woocommerce Get product tags in array

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to get the product tags of the woocommerce products in an array, for doing if/else logic with it (in_array), but my code doesn't work:

```
<?php 

$aromacheck = array() ; 
$aromacheck = get_terms( 'product_tag') ; 
// echo $aromacheck

?>
```

When echoing $aromacheck, I only get empty Array, though the product tags are existing - visible in the post class.

How can I get the product tags in an array correctly?

**Solution (thanks Noman and nevius):**

```
/* Get the product tag */
$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );

$aromacheck = array();
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $aromacheck[] = $term->slug;
    }
}

/* Check if it is existing in the array to output some value */

if (in_array ( "value", $aromacheck ) ) { 
   echo "I have the value";
}
```

Comment: It *does* return an array of objects. You can't `echo` an array of objects...

Comment: This was really useful

Comment: Hi @Gas, can you move the *Solution* to an answer?  Maybe even marking it as the correct one if warranted. Right now, it's confusing to have a solution in the middle of the question.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You need to loop through the array and create a separate array to check `in_array` because `get_terms` return `object` with in array.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
$term_array = array();
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_array[] = $term->name;
    }
}
```

So, After loop through the array.

You can use **in_array()**. 
Suppose `$term_array` contains tag **black**

```
if(in_array('black',$term_array)) {
 echo 'black exists';
} else { 
echo 'not exists';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works in checking the array, and getting the values (silly me to use echo...), but unfortunately it lists all the tags, and not only the ones used for the product itself. Can it be recoded list only the specific product tags?

Comment: You never asked for that...If you need to do this for a specific product, you can use [`get_the_terms()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms).

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I put `$terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );` and it works great! I edited my post to include complete solution.

Comment: OK, sorry I forgot. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 4):

```
global $product;
$tags = $product->tag_ids;
foreach($tags as $tag) {
   echo get_term($tag)->name;
}
```

Comment: Please, add some description in order to explain your code.

Answer (score 3):

I had to parse an args-array to the get_terms function. Maybe this help other aswell.

```
$args = array(
    'number'     => $number,
    'orderby'    => $orderby,
    'order'      => $order,
    'hide_empty' => $hide_empty,
    'include'    => $ids
);

$product_tags = get_terms( 'product_tag', $args );
```