# Get slug of tags woocommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I try to get a slug name of the tags of my product. Like this

```
   $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product');
$list_tags = [];
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
  $tag = get_the_term_list($post->ID, 'product_tag', '', ',' ); 
  array_push($list_tags, $tag );
endwhile;
return $list_tags;
```

I obtain a list of my tags but I want the slug of this tags.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product');
$list_tags = array()
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' );;
    if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $list_tags = $term->slug;
            array_push($list_tags, $terms );
        }
    }
endwhile;
return $list_tags;
```

Based on: [Woocommerce Get product tags in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904758/woocommerce-get-product-tags-in-array)