# I need to get all tags from woo commerce products in a page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need to display all the product tags as a dropdown on main page. I tried the following code but it did not work.

```
$terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
$term_array = array();
if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_array[] = $term->name;
    }
}
```

It always returns an empty array. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Woocommerce Get product tags in array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31904758/woocommerce-get-product-tags-in-array)

Comment: I tried that solution and it not worked.

Comment: What is "main page"?

Comment: Like an index page, or home page. For my case, I tried to write a function in themes function.php file to get all tags for woo-commerce products. I can get id, title and contents but not tags. Bellow here is another piece of code snippet I tried and still no luck :

Comment: $args = array('post_type' => 'product');
    $list_tags = array();
    $loop = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        $terms = get_the_terms(get_the_ID(), 'product_tag');;
        if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
            foreach ($terms as $term) {
                $list_tags = $term->slug;
                array_push($list_tags, $terms);
            }
        }
    endwhile;
    return $list_tags;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not certain what you mean by `dropdown`, but will use `<select>` for this answer.

In your functions.php

```
function get_some_tags_man(){
    $terms = get_terms( array( 
        'hide_empty' => false, // only if you want to hide false
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag',
     ) 
    );
    $html = '';
    if($terms){
        $html .= '<select name="terms" id="someID">';
        foreach($terms as $term){
            $html .= "<option name='$term->name'>$term->name</option>";
        }
        $html .= '</select>';
    }
    return $html;
}
```

in your theme file:

```
<?php echo get_some_tags_man(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the code (in the product page and Shop page) and it worked.
Main Page you mean Shop Page? The first page that appear when you enter the site.
The theme i'm using is StoreFront.
Can you show the hook you are using? or the code? Look. This is the complete code I use.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_product_loop_tags', 15 );
    function woocommerce_product_loop_tags() {
        global $post, $product;

        $tag_count = sizeof( get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_tag' ) );
        $idProducto=$product->id;
         $product->get_title();
        echo $product->get_tags( ', ', '<span class="tagged">' . _n( 'Tag:', 'Tags:', $tag_count, 'woocommerce' ) . ' ', '.</span>' );

        $terms = get_terms( 'product_tag' );
        $term_array = array();
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                    echo " ".$term_array[] = $term->name;
             }
        }
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried the code in function.php and it did not worked :(

Comment: I need that code in function.php for a function say get_all_product_tags(){} and later called it in the home page. But it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will also show empty tags.

```
$terms = get_terms( array( 'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', 'hide_empty' => false ) );
```

Comment: Perfect Bro ! Worked like a charm !